# w3 validator for GitHub published HTML5 page

Tags: html, github

I have an Html5 page published on GitHub it has a anchor link which is

```
<a href="http://validator.w3.org/check/referer"> <img src="http://mumstudents.org/cs472/2014-09/images/w3c-html.png"
alt="html validator" /></a>
```

used to take to the validator page and validate the page, but since the GitHub published pages are https I keep getting error of
[image showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT33w.png)

is there a way to make the validator accept https URLs or change the GitHub published pages to http?

Answer (score 0):

See [`Referrer-Policy` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy)

Youy should be able to specify `referrerpolicy="unsafe-url"`

Comment: the same problem keeps rising